# $A=\begin{bmatrix} \sin (\pi/18) & -\sin (4\pi/9) \\\ \sin (4\pi/9) &\sin (\pi/18)\end{bmatrix} $ find number $n\in N$ such that $A^n=I$?

Tags: calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A=\begin{bmatrix} \sin (\pi/18) & -\sin (4\pi/9) \\ \sin (4\pi/9) &\sin (\pi/18)\end{bmatrix} $ find number $n\in N$ such that $A^n=I$.  I found eigen values and eigen vectors  and use it to find the value of n but it is lengthy , is there another way of solving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} \sin (\pi/18) & -\sin (4\pi/9) \\ \sin (4\pi/9) &\sin (\pi/18)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos (\pi/2-\pi/18) & -\sin (4\pi/9) \\ \sin (4\pi/9) &\cos (\pi/2-\pi/18)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos (4\pi/9) & -\sin (4\pi/9) \\ \sin (4\pi/9) &\cos (4\pi/9)\end{bmatrix} $$
$$\therefore A^9=I$$

Comment: Or formulated as a hint: How does one know that $\det A=1$ in the first place?